# Subscribe to a topic using parent class function as the Callback

Tags: c++, function, pointers, ros

So I'm building a robot code framework and I've got an issue with getting a bit of it to compile.  I've got a class called Behavior that is extended to create all behaviors.  I've got a series of callback functions implemented in it that are required for all behaviors.  However I cannot use the parent classes function as the callback function given a child of the behavior classes. (fyi this is c++). I suspect this has something to do with function pointers in C++ that i dont understand. Would any of you be able to explain how this could be done?

Comment: It seems you define the behavior function in derived class and children classes will override them and you want to use children classes' function as the callback function, right?

Comment: Um no actually what I've got is a function defined in then parent class whose function pointer needs to be passed in the main function. I only have an instance of the child class to work with

Answer (score 1):

You are a bit light on context here, but would something like this help:

```
class Behaviour {
public:
    void callback1() {
        child_behaviour1();
    }
private:
    virtual void child_behaviour1() = 0;
}
```

and then provide the necessary behaviout in `child_behaviour1()` in you derived class and use `Behaviour::*callback1` as you pointer?

Comment: Ya sorry about that. But the thing is I would prefer not to have reimplement the function in question because it is the same for all child classes.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using function pointer in C++.

Write function pointer(for the functions in derived classes) using typedef in your base class.Also write function to register derived class callback functions like below:

**Behaviour.cpp**

```
typedef (*CALLBCK)(in,int); 

class Behavior {

  CALLBCK  funToBeCalled;

  void register_callback(CALLBCK funPtr )
  {
          funToBeCalled = funPtr ;                      
  }

}
```

Once you do this you can register your call back functions of derived class from derived class code using register_callback.

**Derived.cpp**

```
class derived:public Behaviour{

inline void custom(int,int)
{
   ur custom code
}

inline void somefun(){
..
..
register_callback(custom);
..
}



}
```

Once registration of call back function is done you can call your custom derived class function from your base class using funToBeCalled(your function pointer in base)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Behavior {
  virtual void callback_func1() {}
}

class RunBehavior : Behavior {
  void callback_func1() {
    //to run ?
  }
}

//somewhere using callback_func1()
Behavior b = new RunBehavior();
b.callback_func1();
```

This should meet your need based on your description.